# Sequence of solutions to heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following question for homework:

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded and open and let $u_i$ satisfy the heat equation $\partial_t u_i - \Delta u_i = 0$ in $U_T$ := $U \times (0, t]$ and $u_i = g_i$ on $\Gamma_T$ (the boundary of $U_T$), where $g_i$ satisfy $g_i \leq g_{i+1} \leq K$ for all $i$, with $K$ a fixed constant. Show that $\lim u_i = u$ is a solution of the heat equation $\partial_tu - \Delta u = 0$ in $U_T$ with $u = \lim g_i$ on $\Gamma_T$

I've been told about Dini's theorem which says that if a monotonically increasing sequence of functions converges pointwise to $f$ on a compact set then the convergence is uniform. I think I have a rough idea of how to use this here but I'm not entirely sure.  Since $\Gamma_T$ is compact we can apply Dini's theorem to the functions $g_i$. I think I'm supposed to use the mean value formula for the heat equation and then use the fact that the limit of an integral is the integral of a limit for uniformly converging sequences of functions, but I'm not sure of the details.

Does this sound right? One problem I have is that I can't see how the sequence $u_i$ is monotonically increasing in $U_T$ (if it isn't then Dini's theorem doesn't apply)

Answer (score 2):

Your strategy seems like it'll get you there.  To get you past the hurdle of showing the $u_i$ terms are monotone, here's a hint: use the weak maximum principle for the heat equation together with the bounds $g_i \le g_{i+1}$ on $\Gamma_T$.